# How to send and retrieve data to and from a website?

Tags: java, android

Ok, guys, so I'm recently developing android app that takes user's ID to login to website and fetch the data to my phone.

Now, there is login page: http://14.140.201.189:8280/opac/myaccount/myAccount.html

I want to send get and post request and retrieve data corresponding to a username and display it in my style in my android app.I don't want to use WebView for loading the whole web page, as the webpage is not reactive so all components are not at place.

Have you got any thoughts or tips/methods/guides/anything how to do that?

Comment: Can you share some code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple volley API to make request and gather information from database. Get username and password from edittext. Pass to the function give below. Declare necessary all types of variables. Write simple php script for login. This is very simple and basic code.

```
/*************** PASS YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD TO FUNCTION *******************/
public void userValidationInfo(String username, String password){
String url = "url goes here"; // example.com/login.php 
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                JSONArray dataArray;
                JSONObject jsonObject;
                String user_id,user_type,

                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

                        JSONObject obj;
                        try {
                            /***************** GET INFORMATION FROM REQUEST HERE ************************/
                            obj = dataArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            user_id = obj.getString(TAG_USER_ID);
                            user_type = obj.getString(TAG_USER_TYPE);


                            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), brand_names, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               /***************** SET YOUR USER INFO HERE ****************/
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+response);


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        /****************** SHOW WAITING MESSAGE / ERROR MESSAGE HERE *****************/
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Taking bit longer ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}){
/******************** POST YOUR PARAMETERS HERE *************************/
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
    {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
        return params;
    }
};
queue1.add(stringRequest);
}
```

For more information [check this gist](https://gist.github.com/mayur19/0ead078341bc11b45b6842bbbe2fbe62).

Answer (score 2):

**You can't use html page as API.**

1. You need an API(php etc.) which will return data in JSON/XML form not in HTML or any other code like JS.
2. Parse it in your app and do what you want.